# Указание в Jenkins 'динамического' пути

Tags: java, jenkins, jmeter

Есть вообщем JMeter(нагрузочные) которые гоняются на Jenkins. 
Все работает, но тестов много и для каждого из них решил делать Html Publisher.
Все хорошо но в Jenkins не могу правильно сделать(и возможно ли это) настройку пути.
Т.е. путь до теста выглядит примерно так:

```
\target\jmeter\reports\nameOfTJmeterTaste_датаПрогонкиТеста
```

Естественно от времени я не хочу зависеть и хотелось бы узнать - если какой-то спец символ чтобы он подставлял за место него любое количество символов? 
Например:

```
\target\jmeter\reports\nameOfTJmeterTaste_*
```

Есть такая страница - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project , но тут конкретные вариации.

П.С. использую jmeter -maven-plugin https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin

Мб кто знает может в нем можно задать параметры чтобы выводилось только название теста без даты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем если более углубится в jmeter-maven-plugin - там есть настройка pom  файла и настройка

```
  <configuration>
        <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
  </configuration>
```

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Test-Results-File-Format#1 - тут описаны варианты сохранения файла.

Итого от данный проблемы мы избавились, но вопрос остается актуальным : есть ли возможность и как заменить любое количество символов в пути до файла/ов в Jenkins?

UPD
Работающий ответ : [PowerShell - как обрезать название папок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874530/powershell-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: вообщем вышеуказанный метод работает для удаления времени у файла, но почему-то для удаления времени у папок такого метода нет.