# PowerShell - как обрезать название папок

Tags: powershell

В некоторой папке есть несколько папок с названиями :

```
Папка1_дата
Папка2_дата
Папка3_дата
```

Как в powerShell отрезать названия папок до:

```
Папка1
Папка2
Папка3
```

И оставить содержимое данных папок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$directoryPathEMP = "путь до папки где лежат папки/файлы"
foreach ($file in get-ChildItem $directoryPathEMP ) {
    $fileNameString = $file.name; //имя файла/папки 
    $newFileName = $fileNameString.Substring(0, $fileNameString.length - 16); //новое имя файла/папки - 16(в данном случае) знаков
Rename-Item -path $file.FullName -newName $newFileName // переименовываем старое название на новое
  }
```

Можно даже сделать версию с именем юзера:

```
$userName = $env:UserName;
$directoryPathEMP = "путь" + $userName + "путь";
foreach ($file in get-ChildItem $directoryPathEMP ) {
    $fileNameString = $file.name;
    $newFileName = $fileNameString.Substring(0, $fileNameString.length - 16);
    $newFileName;
Rename-Item -path $file.FullName -newName $newFileName
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$Path = 'C:\tmp'; $At = '_';
foreach ($d in [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($Path)){[System.IO.Directory]::Move($d,$d.Remove($d.LastIndexOf($At)))};
```